# Find missing months in js array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following Array

```
[
  { Month: '2021-05', Count: 36 },
  { Month: '2021-06', Count: 1048 },
  { Month: '2021-07', Count: 572 },
  { Month: '2021-09', Count: 3 },
  { Month: '2021-12', Count: 52 },
  { Month: '2022-01', Count: 4 },
  { Month: '2022-02', Count: 273 },
  { Month: '2022-04', Count: 96 }
]
```

where I am missing a few months. I know how many months is needed (could be 12 or could be more or less) and I need the missing months (like 2021-08 in this case) to be added with a count of 0. How to go about it?

Comment: Where does the array come from? Are you creating it using a database or a prgramming language?
If you know your start and end month - you could create a loop to populate all of them with 0 and then loop through your data assigning the values which would leave you with your desired outcome?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [pure, functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) approach which will create a *new* array with *new* items, inserting all of the missing months in order. The code includes some comments explaining the procedure:

```js
const parseDate = str => str.split('-').map(Number);
const formatDate = (year, month) => `${year}-${String(month).padStart(2, '0')}`;

function createContinuousMonthCounts (array) {
  const all = [];
  // get initial year/month values from first item
  let [year, month] = parseDate(array[0].Month);

  const advanceDate = () => {
    month += 1;
    if (month > 12) {
      year += 1;
      month = 1;
    }
  };

  for (const item of array) {
    const [y, m] = parseDate(item.Month);
    // while the current month is not equal to the current item's month,
    // create an entry for the month, append it, and advance to the next month
    while (year !== y || month !== m) {
      all.push({Month: formatDate(year, month), Count: 0});
      advanceDate();
    }
    // after we're up to date, add the current item and advance the date
    all.push({...item});
    advanceDate();
  }

  return all;
}

const array = [
  { Month: '2021-05', Count: 36 },
  { Month: '2021-06', Count: 1048 },
  { Month: '2021-07', Count: 572 },
  { Month: '2021-09', Count: 3 },
  { Month: '2021-12', Count: 52 },
  { Month: '2022-01', Count: 4 },
  { Month: '2022-02', Count: 273 },
  { Month: '2022-04', Count: 96 },
];

const all = createContinuousMonthCounts(array);

for (const {Month, Count} of all) console.log(Month, Count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot into the dark (please consider adding some Code to your question):

```js
const months = [
  { Month: '2021-05', Count: 36 },
  { Month: '2021-06', Count: 1048 },
  { Month: '2021-07', Count: 572 },
  { Month: '2021-09', Count: 3 },
  { Month: '2021-12', Count: 52 },
  { Month: '2022-01', Count: 4 },
  { Month: '2022-02', Count: 273 },
  { Month: '2022-04', Count: 96 }
];

const neededMonths = [
  "2021-01","2021-02","2021-03","2021-04","2021-05","2021-06","2021-07","2021-08","2021-09","2021-10","2021-11","2021-12"
]

const missedMonths = [];

months.map( m => {
  if(neededMonths.indexOf(m.Month) == -1 ){
    missedMonths.push(m.Month);
  }
});

console.log(missedMonths);
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need a method to find all the months between a range, then iterate across all the months and add the missing ones with `count: 0`:

```js
const months = [
  { Month: '2021-05', Count: 36 },
  { Month: '2021-06', Count: 1048 },
  { Month: '2021-07', Count: 572 },
  { Month: '2021-09', Count: 3 },
  { Month: '2021-12', Count: 52 },
  { Month: '2022-01', Count: 4 },
  { Month: '2022-02', Count: 273 },
  { Month: '2022-04', Count: 96 }
]

const firstMonth = months.at(0).Month;
const lastMonth = months.at(-1).Month;

const [initialYear, initialMonth] = firstMonth.split('-');
const [endingYear, endingMonth] = lastMonth.split('-');

const allMonths = [];

let currentMonth = initialMonth;
let currentYear = initialYear;
while (`${currentYear}-${(''+currentMonth).padStart(2, '0')}` !== lastMonth) {
  allMonths.push(`${currentYear}-${(''+currentMonth).padStart(2, '0')}`);
  currentMonth++;
  if (currentMonth === 13) {
    currentMonth = 1;
    currentYear++;
  }
}

allMonths.forEach(month => {
  if (!months.find(m => m.Month === month)) {
     months.push({Month: month, count: 0});
  }
});

console.log(months);
```